# How to prevent dupes in tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I joined two tables using following query. It is giving me duplicates because Table02 has duplicates. I need to prevent dupes.

Note:

1. I can't change the order/sequence of the columns in my select statment.
2. I can't use distinct on t1.NumberID.

   SELECT t1.NumberID, t1.Copies, t1.NameStreet 
   FROM Table01 t1 
   JOIN Table02 t2 
   on t2.Name = LEFT(t1.NameStreet, Len(t2.Name)) order by t1.NumberID, t1.Namestreet

**Table01**

```
ID  NumberID    Copies      NameStreet
1   11111111    2           Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
2   22222222    1           Brad Pit 200 Loaden Blvd, Toronto
3   11111111    0           Allen Sunderland 9, Unit 2, Janet Street, BC
```

Table02

```
ID  Name
1   Julian Assange
2   Allen Sunderland 
3   Julian Assange
```

Results:-

```
1   11111111    2           Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
3   11111111    0           Allen Sunderland 9, Unit 2, Janet Street, BC
1   11111111    2           Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
```

Expected Results:-

```
1   11111111    2           Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
3   11111111    0           Allen Sunderland 9, Unit 2, Janet Street, BC
```

Comment: Change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end of the query:

```
GROUP BY  t1.NumberID, t1.Copies, t1.NameStreet
```

Comment: Sorry. I have order by clause in the end of the select statement. I have added it into the question.